# Force logoff users who were logged in via Fiori launchpad

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-gui, logoff

We know that Fiori launchpad in frontend communicates with background by a stateless technology.
But now there is a demand that all users have to be logged off forcefully, no matter whether these users were logged in by SAP GUI or Fiori launchpad. When a report program is running in SAP GUI, all users have to be logged off.

Now what I know are:

- Function module `TH_DELETE_USER` is useful for users who logged in by SAP GUI.
- Those users who were logged in by Fiori launchpad can't logoff by this FM or `SM04` without any error message.
- Launchpad users can't be logged out by deleting security sessions in `SM05`.

Could anyone tell me whether there are methods which could invalidate launchpad user authentications?
ABAP methods are best, but other technologies are welcome too.

Comment: Have you tried calling `sap.ushell.Container.logout()`?

Comment: I didn't try this method, but I think this could only logoff the user do call this method.

Comment: do you use on-prem S4HANA or cloud? or maybe you are using ECC? do you want to logoff only silently i.e. without error message?